# Split a dataframe in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, split

My data frame is as follows:

```
User  
JohnLenon03041965  
RogerFederer12021954  
RickLandsman01041975
```

and I am trying to get the output as

```
Name     Lastname    Birthdate  
John     Lenon       03041965      
Roger    Federer     12021954  
Rick     Landsman    01041975
```

I tried the following code:

```
**a = gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', df$User)
a <- as.data.frame(a)
library(tidyr)
a <-separate(a, a, into = c("Name", "Last"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)")**
```

I get the following:

```
Name  Last  
John  Lenon03041965  
Roger Federer12021954  
Rick  Landsman01041975
```

I am trying to use the separate condition like (?=[0-9]) but getting error like this:

```
c <-separate(c, c, into = c("last", "date"), sep = '(?=[0-9])')
```

> *Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  :    argument is of length zero*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround as `sep` by specifying either to split between a lower case letter and an upper case (`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`) or (`|`) between a lower case letter and a number (`(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]+)`)

```
df1 %>%
   separate(User, into = c("Name", "LastName", "Birthdate"),
         sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9]+)")
#   Name LastName Birthdate
#1  John    Lenon  03041965
#2 Roger  Federer  12021954
#3  Rick Landsman  01041975
```

---

Or another option is `extract` to capture characters as a group by placing it inside the brackets (`(...)`).  Here, the 1st capture group matches an upper case letter followed by one or more lower case letters (`([A-Z][a-z])`) from the start (`^`) of the string, 2nd captures one or more characters that are not numbers (`([^0-9]+)`) and in the 3rs, it is the rest of the characters (`(.*)`)

```
df1 %>% 
    extract(User, into = c("Name", "LastName", "Birthdate"),
           "^([A-Z][a-z]+)([^0-9]+)(.*)")
#   Name LastName Birthdate
#1  John    Lenon  03041965
#2 Roger  Federer  12021954
#3  Rick Landsman  01041975
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(User = c("JohnLenon03041965", "RogerFederer12021954", 
"RickLandsman01041975")), .Names = "User", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: just worked it out. works very well. i  think my lack of awareness in 'sep' conditions was less. thanks!

Comment: Fantastic solution. I was just wondering which one to prefer `extract` or `separate`? In terms of performance.

Comment: @MKR Thanks, I haven't done any benchmarks.  Please feel free to do so and post it as an answer